# Trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 along side Win10 in Legacy mode, getting "no efi system partition was found" error

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

Basically what the title says. I have chosen the "something else" option since for some reason windows 10 wasn't being detected. I created a root partition, swap partition, home partition and I even tried to create a `/boot` partition (didn't work neither with nor without it).

The problem is that after I click "Install", I get "no EFI system partition was found. etc". The thing is, I want to use Legacy mode, not UEFI, since Windows is in Legacy. Am I doing something wrong? I tried to look on google, but I couldn't really find something for this specific problem. I found how to install in UEFI mode when this error occurs, I found how to install in Legacy mode but this error wasn't occurring in the articles that I looked at.

Comment: Please add `mount |grep target` to your question.  and `[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen if you boot the installer in UEFI mode and want to install. Then the installer wants to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode as well and requires that the partition table of the target device is in GPT format and has an ESP partition.

Check in your BIOS how you boot from the installer device. You don't want to boot the installer in UEFI mode but in Legacy mode. Sometimes the options to boot in UEFI mode have UEFI in the boot entry, e.g. at the end, and the legacy option doesn't.

Comment: Thank you, turns out this was the problem. Now, I saw some people say that I can just remove the `EFI` folder from the USB and it will automatically boot in Legacy mode. I did this just to test, and it worked, however my question is: is this ok to do, or could it mess up things later? I don't think it should, but I don't know

Comment: I'm not convinced removing the /EFI/ folder would make all UEFI based bootloaders ignore the vmlinuz file in the /casper/ folder, but as a quick and dirty solution it might suffice. There's of course also the issue, that you sometimes can't change the contents of the installer device (e.g. when `usb-creator-gtk` flashed/burned the installer device).

I don't believe there will be an issue later if you install it like this.

Answer (score 0):

I have Win11 booted in Legacy, and have loaded Linux installer from USB stick in Legacy too. I have removed EFI folder before from USB installer stick. Then still message appear about "no efi system partition was found" error. I have Lattitude E5570, SDRAM 8 GB (DDR4), Dell BIOS Revision 1.32.3, boot mode is set to: LEGACY; Secure Boot: OFF.
I have checked in terminal: lsblk -f, that was proposed in mint forum: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=378502, but nothing strange I found. So, I just choose to continue installation on my own risk: succeed - the only problem that on dualboot menu of windows option is seen with text "..repair.." but windows is working OK (no repair need).